# Continuously refresh SVG from server coordinates

Tags: html, svg

Say I have a web server that contains a table like this which updates/changes once per second.  Table can be stored in static file, SQL database, or in memory because it's very small.

Table contains three fields with Object Name, X coordinate, Y coordinate.  Table has the following data.

- A, 22, 4
- B, 12, 3
- C, 6, 7

The table might be stored in a static file, a SQL database, or just in memory since it's a very small amount of data.

I want to render an HTML page on a web client that contains a PNG image background.  Then continuously render three circles representing object A, B, and C over the PNG image based on their X Y coordinates once per second.

I want to avoid redrawing the entire HTML page once per second for performance reasons.  What is the best way to dynamically update the HTML page without reloading the entire HTML page?  I read that it might be possible to just continuously reload the SVG file and overlay that circle over a PNG but even the SVG file is quite bloated when I all want to transmit is the coordinate change.

Is this possible?

Comment: You don't need to resend the whole SVG or page.  You just need to have some Javascript on the page that fetches the updated coordinates using an AJAX call. Then updates the page dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for responding Paul.  So once the AJAX call pulls new coordinates, it can redraw the circles at their new locations?

Comment: I searched some more before your response and found that it might be possible to use progressive SVG streaming.  That way I won't need to request the data from the server needlessly causing more bandwidth and processing load. http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/streaming/#progressive-download-and-rendering-of-graphics-animations